# Why is my css not editing my html button height?

Tags: html, css, button, height, edit

I am trying to edit this button and for some reason, it only changes certain attributes of the button even though I was able to edit my other buttons exactly how I wanted.

Here is my code for the button:

```css
.family button {
  height: 10%;
  width: 10%;
}
```

```html
<div class="family"><button>$500/mnth</button></div>
```

Can someone please help?

Comment: please specify how you actually want your button. Its unclear to me what you are actually trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

The height in percentages (%) is of the parent element (DIV in your case). So if the DIV is already 10x the size that you want your button to be (I assume that from your 10% values) then the button will not seem to change but it actually is.

Comment: so how do I get it to appear like it has changed and be the same size as my other buttons which are also in percentages?

Comment: You either make each button a set size in pixels, e.g. `width: 25px; height: 20px;` or make sure that the div is indeed 10x bigger than your buttons.

Comment: Okay, so how do I make sure the div is 10x bigger? I didn't have to do this for my other two buttons, it edited the way I wanted. I assume it's because the div was already 10x bigger, but how do I change that?

Comment: You can once again set it to a defined pixel size. Mind that it will actually take up that much space on the screen too then and everything else will be pushed away to give your DIV element space. Unless you have set it to float over other elements in your HTML.